# Check for Windows version in Silktest Classic Open agent 2011

Tags: automated-testing

I am new to [Silktest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SilkTest), so can anyone help me out to verify the Windows version and the IE browser that the test is about to run on.

Is there an inbuilt function that I could use in my test case that would actually pull th

Comment: Looks like your last sentence is unfinished. What is "pull th"?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `SYS_GetName` function.

From the doc:

> Returns the name of the operating system on the target system, where the 4Test Agent is running.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SilkTest, but I understand that it supports C#. In C# you can get browser info via the [HttpRequest.Browser property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and you could use the [System.PlatformID enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a8hyw88.aspx) and the [System.Environment.OSVersion property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx), or for more detailed OS info you invoke some Win32 APIs described [in my blog here](http://www.testingmentor.com/imtesty/2010/03/03/programmatically-detecting-the-operating-system-version-part-ii/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tehlexx's answer, you can also try `SYS_GetVersion()`, which returns the Microsoft specified constant that specifies the OS being used.

If you're doing web testing or some kind of non-trivial parallel/network testing, I would try avoiding using `SYS_` functions, however since they're highly machine dependent. You could also try writing custom functions that pull the OS information from the regional settings or elsewhere directly from the machine the test is being run on.